# Get product Url in custom module Observer.php file Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite

In custom module `Observer.php` i am trying to get Product url

On view.phtml it gives correct working path like `http://websitename.com/brave-gentleman-new-york-belt.html`

But same code in `Observer.php` gives `http://websitename.com/brave-gentleman-new-york-belt-120.html`

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
Mage::log( $_product->getProductUrl());
```

This code gives `brave-gentleman-new-york-belt` which is correct but it is not complete url

```
 $productURL = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')
  ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore());
```

This gives the result

```
$productUrl  = Mage::getBaseUrl().Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore()).Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProductUrlSuffix();
```

Comment: which event is observed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this ...

```
# returns string "product-url.html"
$productUrl = Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite')
    ->getRequestPathByIdPath('product/' . $productId, $storeId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code also

```
$baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
$id = 404; // enter your product id
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$urlPath = $product->getUrlPath();

$productUrl = $baseUrl.$urlPath;
```